# How to enable UTF-8 for the subject when I perform Mail2Blogger in PHPMail function?

Tags: php, blogger

Assume that I have a table in my database which has the record in Portuguese like *São João Na Mississipi Com*.

When I do the phpMail function to send email to blogger[dot]com by utilizing the Mail2Blogger function of blogger platform, it becomes like this:*SÃ£o JoÃ£o Na Mississipi Com*

This is my php code:

```
$email = 'ericxxx.xyz@blogger.com';
$recipient = urlencode($email);
$subject = $row['subject']; //assume this is a record in the table in my database
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Me<info@domain[dot]com>\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .='Reply-To: 'Me<info@domain[dot]com'>'."\r\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/'. phpversion();
//$headers .= "Cc:'anotheMe@domain[dot]com'\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
$body = "<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$subject}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Bla bla bla
        </div>
    </body>
       </html>";
    mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

As you can see, the `$headers` has the Content-type already.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?